# javascript object not updating to added value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object `State().score` that should be updated with it's added value when it is being called in `Handler().addToScore()`. The thing is that it always stays at it's initial value which is `0`.

```
const DOM = () => {
  const dom = {}

  dom.score = document.getElementsByClassName('score')[0]

  return dom
}

const State = () => {
  const state = {}

  state.score = 0 // This remains 0, I want it to update when adding to it

  return state
}

const Handler = () => {
  const handler = {}

  handler.addToScore = function() { 
    State().score += 10

    console.log(State().score) // Equals to 0 on every click and never gets updated

    DOM().score.innerHTML = State().score
  }

  return handler
}

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  if(response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log( 'Logged in and authenticated' )
    Handler().addToScore()
  } else {
    console.log('Not authenticated')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every-time you run `State()` it sets returns a fresh object with `score` being `0`

You will have to save the outcome of the intialization of your `State().score` if you want it to be saved. Or, you can change up the way that you're generating `score` by using a `get`ter and a `set`ter

```js
const State = () => {
  const state = {}

  state.score = 0 // This remains 0, I want it to update when adding to it

  return state
}

console.log(State().score); // State() is a function that ALWAYS returns { score: 0 }
let savedScore = State().score;
savedScore += 1;
console.log(savedScore);
```

Example using `get`/`set` (there's multiple ways to do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/1ds8mbqw/3/

```
class State {
    constructor() {
    this._score = 0;
  }
  get score() {
    return this._score;
  }
  set score(val) {
    this._score = val;
  }
}

const state = new State();
console.log(state.score);
state.score += 1;
console.log(state.score);
```

One other way to do this, of course, it to not make `State` a function. It looks like you're actually trying to manage a score or state so having `State` be a function that ultimately gives you a brand new state (score) everytime isn't going to work.

Something as simple as just not having `State` be a function would also work:

```
const State = () => {
  const state = {}

  state.score = 0 // This remains 0, I want it to update when adding to it

  return state
}
```

Should be

```
const State = {
  score: 0
};
```